# Passing Div ID Dynamically from Rails controller to js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating an application which has tasks and users can like and comment to the tasks. I am bringing the like and comments feature in the index page itself.

Index page renders comments partial for every task:

tasks/_comments.html.erb

```
<div class="comments-div">
<% if comments.present? %>
<% comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment-div">
        <div><img src="/assets/user.png" class="comment-img">
        <p class='comment-desc'><%= comment.description %></p></div>
        <p class="height-10">User: <%= comment.user.name %></span>
            <span class="right">Commented On: <%= comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y") %></span>     
        </p>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="comments-form">
            <%= form_for :comment, url: "comments/add_comments", remote: true, html: { id: 'comment-form' } do |form| %>

              <%= form.hidden_field :task_id, value: task_id %>
              <div class="search-fields">
                <%= form.text_area :description %>
              </div>

              <div>
                <%= form.submit 'Comment', id: 'ad-comment-btn', remote: true, 'data-task-id' => task_id, click: 'form_action(this);' %>
              </div>
            <% end  %>

</div>
```

This js gets executed on add comment form submit.

application.js

```
    $('.comments-form form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var taskId = this.elements[1].value;
    var description = this.elements[2].value;
    var comment_params = JSON.stringify({task_id: taskId, description: description});
    $.post("/comments/add_comments?comment=" + comment_params);
    return false;
})
```

comments_controller:

```
def add_comments
    comment_params = JSON.parse(params[:comment])
    comment_params.merge!({user_id: current_user.id})
    @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
    @task_container_id = "task-comments-container_#{comment_params['task_id']}"
    @comments = Comment.where(task_id: comment_params["task_id"]).to_a
    @task_id = comment_params["task_id"]

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment created Successfully"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Something went wrong. Try again"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
  format.js       
end
end
```

I am passing the @task_container_id from controller and trying to use it in js.erb file.

add_comments.js.erb

```
$('#"<%= @task_container_id %>"').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tasks/comments', locals: { comments: @comments, task_id: @task_id } ) %>");
```

I want to replace the div id here  $('#"<%= @task_container_id %>"') which is passed by the controller. But div is not refreshing as expected. if I hard code the div id in js.erb file, refresh is happening properly.

How do I fix it?

Comment: not replacing properly in the sense what? what is happening?

Comment: first of all are you getting element by task container id?

Comment: comments div is not refreshing as expected. If I hard code the div id, refresh is happening. task_container_id is the div element id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very minor mistake that I have done.

add_comments.js.erb

```
$("#<%= @task_container_id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tasks/comments', locals: { comments: @comments, task_id: @task_id } ) %>");
```

Had to remove an extra single quote ("#'<%= @task_container_id %>'") to simply $("#<%= @task_container_id %>")

Answer (score 0):

In your `aplication.js` the `elements array is zero based`, so change the value to 0 and 1 respectively while fetching the taskId and description

```
var taskId = this.elements[0].value;
var description = this.elements[1].value;
```

----------------------- UPDATED --------------------------

I guess I found the mistake

in your controller

change `@task_id = comment_params["task_id"]` to @task_id = `comment_params[:task_id]`

[image]

Comment: ajax is passing the taskId and description properly. I am able to save it as well. The problem is I am not able to replace the element ID in js.erb.

Comment: if you use comment_param.fetch("task_id") it will also show you the error

Comment: As i do  JSON.stringify({task_id: taskId}) from my ajax request, commenbt_params[:task_id] will not work. Only comment_params["task_id"] will work. Also I debugged to rule out these kind of issues and i have finally come to js.erb file and that is where the element id is not replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following,

`escape_javascript` is aliased to `j` so you can use it.
I assumed that you are already getting the element with this dynamic ID and already rendering `'tasks/comments'` partial in that div with dynamic ID.

add_comments.js.erb

```
$("#'<%= @task_container_id %>'").html("<%= j render(partial: 'tasks/comments', locals: { comments: @comments, task_id: @task_id } ) %>");
```

Good luck!

Comment: No Luck :( I think the problem is with replacing the element ID. Because if I hard code the element ID , auto refresh is happening as expected.